# Properly switch to dark theme in PDF.JS rendered inside a QWebView

Tags: pdf.js, pyqt6, qwebengineview

I am trying to display a PDF using `PDF.JS` inside a `QWebEngineView` with the code below

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt6.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
import sys

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pdfjs = "file:///D:/CODING RELATED/Projects/Import Manager/pdfjs-2.15.349-legacy-dist/web/viewer.html"

        pdf_url = QUrl().fromUserInput(f"{pdfjs}?file=file:///C:/Users/Eliaz/Desktop/qt5cadaquesPart14.pdf")

        self.preview = QWebEngineView()
        self.preview.load(pdf_url)
        self.preview.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, it is using the light theme but I need to change it to dark theme. Digging deeper into this problem, I found these related issues [#12290](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/12290) and [#14059](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14059). I found out that I should set the **`viewerCssTheme`** attribute/property to **`2`** which sets the theme to dark mode.
Having not so long experience using `QWebEngineView`, I have no idea how to set its value programmatically inside PyQt6. With no choice left I just hard-coded the value of it on lines **175** and **20450** in `web\viewer.js`.

[image]
[image]

**This is what it looks like after hard-coding the values:**
[image]

---

As you can see it switched to the dark theme but with **some bad side effects like the `scroll-thumb` still white** which should be dark gray.

**My question:** Is this how I properly switch to a dark theme in PDF.JS which is rendered inside a QWebEngineView?

Comment: The fact that you're using a dark theme in Firefox is completely irrelevant, since Qt uses *its own* web engine, and it is also based on Chromium.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is being connected/related in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pondering it for a while, I just decided to stick on using the way of hard coding it as I can't find a way to tell Qt's WebView to change my preferred theme. Additionally, hard coding the values seems to just create one minor visible flaw which is the white scrollbar track. To solve that, I just need to add these lines in the `web\viewer.css`:

These overrides the scrollbar's thumb and track color, You can learn more info about this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/QtFramework/comments/jwe0qr/comment/gctb5z5/).

```
#viewerContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 11px;
}

#viewerContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--scrollbar-color)
}

#viewerContainer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--scrollbar-bg-color);
}
```

This is what it looks like now:
[image]